# what is difference between resources and data sources in terraform documentation for a particular terraform provider?

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-aws

[resources and data sources](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qtXGf.png) in terraform documentation [link](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/resources/eip_association), can anyone explain their difference and example scenario where they can be used

Answer (score 5, accepted):

- [Data Sources](https://www.terraform.io/language/data-sources): Allow Terraform to use information defined outside of Terraform, defined by another separate Terraform configuration, or modified by functions.
- [Resources](https://www.terraform.io/language/resources): Each resource block describes one or more infrastructure objects, such as virtual networks, compute instances, or higher-level components such as DNS records.

Answer (score 0):

To understand the difference consider this scenario:

- You develop a cloud solution that consists of services that consume
  data from a database.
- You are not the owner of the database, a customer or another team owns the database.
- Your services need to know some database properties like host name, ports...etc

Using a data source that refers to the database you can get information of the database that you need in your terraform configuration.